# Serializing/Deserializing settings and dealing with ever changing model

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8

### Background

My app uses multiple `ResourceDictionary` in order to store its settings.
When closing the app, the settings are written in `XAML` files.

This is the load order (if setting is missing from location, jump to the other):

1. Local: Local settings, portable, stored inside the same folder as the main executable.
2. AppData: Global settings, non-portable, stored in the AppData folder.
3. Default: Default settings, evergreen, embedded in the main executable.

When the user closes the app, the settings that are different than the default ones are written to the Local or AppData folders (preference for the local one) as a simple XAML file, a `ResourceDictionary` with properties inside.

### Limitations

I'm working with a single executable app, so I'm staying clear of dependencies.
Because of that, I use plain text files as my storage method.

### Issue

Since I'm serializing and deserializing XAML files using the standard `XamlWriter`/`XamlReader`, I'm susceptible to exceptions when the model changes.

I can detect faulty lines (when one line has a property that won't load because of a model change) and remove them, but since I'm also storing complex types with child properties, it doesn't help a lot.

### Ideas

I'm thinking about versioning each settings file and migrate up/down settings when needed (when being loaded by a mismatching model).

This would solve my issues, but it will require a change in how the settings are being stored and loaded.

### Question

I need a simple way of storing properties (Name, Type, Value) that can be read one by one, with a special case for complex types (Arrays, types with child properties).

I wonder if there's something already baked into .NET (not being the Properties class, which has other problems) or something that can be altered to work like I need so.

If nothing available, how would you create something like that?

Comment: Maybe `Isolated Storage`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/isolated-storage

Comment: I don't think so, there's no control of where the data is stored, right?